# SwiftUI DatePicker format is different on each device, how to make it always display the same chosen version?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, datepicker

SwiftUI DatePicker in my app is displayed in three different formats:

In Xcode Preview:

[image]

In Simulator:

[image]

On Device:

[image]

I wonder, how will the users see it?

I want it to be displayed in the "14 Jul 2022" format, "Jul 14, 2022" is also fine, but I don't like the "7/14/22" format.

Please help me - How can I do it?

EDIT: It's even worse than that (although this happens only on the simulator) - the DatePicker uses different formats in different places in my app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SwiftUI `DatePicker` adheres to the user's locale and date settings. On iPhone, you can change them in the system settings *General > Language & Region* as well as *General > Date & Time*. Usually, you should not mess with the format of the `DatePicker` since if you hard-code a specific format a user from a different region may get confused.

You can override the locale and thus the formatting if you really insist on overriding the user's preference:

```
DatePicker(…)
    .environment(\.locale, Locale(…))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set locale explicitly to `DatePicker`, like

```
DatePicker(
    // ... other things

    displayedComponents: .date
)
.environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "us"))  // << here !!
```

Documentation:

[image: demo]